# PyQT/PySide vs PyObjC: worth it?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyobjc, pyside

I'm thinking of creating a cross platform app, but I want it to look as natively as possible on OS X, is PyObjC a good choice? How easy is it? In contrast, how good is QT when it comes to looking native?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure if my answer is in your request. But let me say one thing - take a look at [Route Buddy](http://www.routebuddy.com/routebuddy) which is developed in Qt for OSX and it is a good example that ii is sometimes hard to distinguish if it's a native Cocoa application or not. 
Another - but bad - example is [SlickEdit](http://www.slickedit.com/) , which has IMO a quite ugly GUI.

Comment: Route Buddy looks awesome, any idea how they made the titlebar blend with the rest of the menu? I havent seen anything that made that possible yet.

Comment: Simple thoughts - they create an [unified toolbar](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#id-cd0a6e08-63f9-468f-a780-694b78076daa) and sets the active icon blend with Qt Stylesheets, which is a kind of CSS (btw, a killer feature).